# How to show/hide an item of array.map() based on onclick inside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router, jsx

I want to show/hide a part of JSX depending on `P_Gamestate` property. If this is in progress we will only show the component we clicked on. Else everything else should be hidden. This is difficult since the `.map()` refers to all elements in the playlists. How can I achieve this?
Currently it will hide the component i clicked on,but everything else will remain shown.

challenges.js:

```
export default function Challenges()
{
    const [P_gameState, P_setGameState] = useState(GAME_STATE.BEFORE);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function getPlaylists() {
           let querySnapshot =  await firestoreRef
            .collection('challenge_test')
            .get();
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(data) {
                playlist.push([useful data]);
            });
        }
        getPlaylists();

    },[]);
    return(
        <div>
            <header>
                {console.log("rendering component...")}
                {playlist.map((row)=> (

                        <CardComponent key={row[0]}
                                       name={row[0]}
                                       image={row[1]}
                                       creator={row[2]}
                                       challengeID={row[3]}
                                       P_gameState={P_gameState}
                        />
                )
                )
}         
        </div>
    );
}
```

card-component.js

```
function CardComponent(props) {
    const [gameState, setGameState] = useState(GAME_STATE.BEFORE);

    const onClick = () => {
        console.log(props.history);
        props.history.push("/playchallenge");
    };
    return (
        <div>
        { gameState === GAME_STATE.BEFORE &&
        <div className='card-component'>
            <Button onClick={() => setGameState(GAME_STATE.IN_PROGRESS)}>
                <img
                    className="playlist-image"
                    src={props.image}
                    alt={props.name} />
            </Button>
            <h3 className='playlist-title'>{props.name}</h3>
            <h4 className='playlist-creator-text'>Created by {props.creator}</h4>
        </div>
    }
     { gameState === GAME_STATE.IN_PROGRESS &&   <FetchData />}
</div>

    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do conditional rendering in JSX, you have multiple methods:

1. Branching inside the `map` function callback

```
array.map(item => {
  if (!condition) {
    return null;
  }
  return <Component {...props} />;
});
```

2. Branching inside the component render function (similar to method 1)
3. Call `array.filter` before `map` (this will create a new copy of the filtered array every time)
4. Inline If with logical && operator

```
array.map(item => condition && <Component {...props} />);
```

5. Inline If with Conditional (ternary) operator

```
array.map(item => condition? <Component {...props} />: <SomethingElse />);
```

===========

If you want the condition to be updated by some event occurs in the inside components, use an event prop

```
<CardComponent onClick={() => { /* do something with your game state */ }} />
```

Comment: Thank you for this. How can I identify a particular array in my array.map()? It is actually an array of arrays.

Comment: I think that you want to update the condition on the event of the inside component click, so I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, as I was doing this I ran into a cosmetic issue. I want my components to be listed side by side but since i return each one in the jsx, they are all listed one on top of the other. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Please look at this for reference: https://codepen.io/tonioshikanlu/pen/ZEbGEoN